# ASP.NET User Controls Popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, popup

I'm currently developing fixes for a website at work. It was built by another developer long before I came to the company and so I am having a bit of a problem understanding with the way his code works.

Basically here is the gist:
There are pages named ParentPage.aspx, ChildControl.ascx, and MyPopup.ascx. The ChildControl.ascx contains a few divs which becomes visible depending on where it will be used. For this matter let's say we have DivA and DivB. Now what the page is doing is this. Whenever ParentPage.aspx loads up, it loads DivA from ChildControl.ascx into the page. So everything that's inside DivA gets loaded on the webpage. Now on DivA contains a repeater. Say we have 3 rows of items generated. In each of the item, there is a button that would popup DivB when it's clicked. So then DivB pops-up with data depending on which item was clicked on the repeater. That is the existing design of the webpage. Now my problem is on this one, we have a new requirement where we need to popup MyPopup.ascx when a button inside DivB is clicked.

I don't know if everything makes full sense but that is how the current website is working and that is how client requirements look like right now. I'm starting to flip out because I absolutely don't know where and how to start. We currently use JavaScript on the website's design.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to load an iFrame inside the DivB button click occurs. The iframe would call an aspx page that just contains the ascx file, and passes in the querystring parameters whatever the ascx needs to brind the data.